# "list index out of range" when reading data from file

Tags: python

Anyone help to explain why this code gives the error as `"list index out of range"`?

I've tried on drawing a graph with text file data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
x,y = [],[]
with open('text.txt','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(int(row[1]))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Text file

```
0, 1
1, 3
2, 7
3, 5
....
```

Result

```
IndexError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f3977bc887cc> in <module>()
      5     plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
      6     for row in plots:
----> 7         x.append(int(row[0]))
      8         y.append(int(row[1]))
      9     plt.legend()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Your file is incorrectly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

As @Megalng pointed out in the comments, the problem is in your text.txt file. I created this file :

```
12, 12
13, 12
14, 12
15, 13
16, 14
17, 14
18, 15
19, 15
20, 15
```

and ran your code to get this graph :

[image]

Comment: My text file is very similar, but the result is ...


IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-3428c759cda3> in <module>()
      8     plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
      9     for row in plots:
---> 10         x.append(int(row[0]))
     11         y.append(int(row[1]))
     12 

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Try to test it with a simpler csv file. Then, if it works, try to visually inspect your csv file.

Comment: I've solved it. If the text file includes more than one empty row after last data, these codes gives the error "list index out of range".